# Promise.resolve() inside async function

Tags: javascript, promise

I read a SO thread somewhere a while back that using static `Promise` methods like `Promise.resolve()` or `Promise.reject()` inside an `async` function are anti-patterns but I can't seem to find it.

Given the following:

```js
const asyncFunc = async (foo) => {
    if (foo) return Promise.resolve()

    return Promise.reject()
}
```

Is this considered an anti-pattern?

Comment: ‘using static Promise methods’ is rather broad, maybe too broad to make general statements about. The particular way you used them here (in a return statement) looks rather bad though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Promise.resolve` is, perhaps not so much an *antipattern* so much as *completely unnecessary*, because returning a plain value from an async function will result in the Promise that it returns resolving to that value.

```
if (foo) return Promise.resolve()
```

is equivalent to

```
if (foo) return;
```

and

```
if (foo) return Promise.resolve(5)
```

is equivalent to

```
if (foo) return 5;
```

So you may as well leave off the `Promise.resolve`.

`Promise.reject` is a bit different. If you want to reject the Promise that the function returns, you may either do `throw <expression>`, or you may do `return Promise.reject<expression>` - both are equivalent, and I don't think there's any concrete reason to prefer one or the other in all circumstances (though I'd prefer `throw` since it's more concise).